# What is the meaning of Spring logback scope attribute of the <springProperty> configuration element?

Tags: spring, logback, spring-logback

Spring defines [the `springProperty` extension](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#environment-properties) to the logback configuration:

```
<springProperty scope="context" name="fluentHost" source="myapp.fluentd.host"
    defaultValue="localhost"/>
```

But I don't see the explanation of what the meaning of `scope="context"` is.

What values can one give to the `scope` attribute and what do they mean?

(I don't see any `context` in the list of [Bean Scopes](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes), in case this has to do anything with it.)

Answer (score 2):

LOCAL SCOPE A property with local scope exists from the point of its definition in a configuration file until the end of interpretation/execution of said configuration file. As a corollary, each time a configuration file is parsed and executed, variables in local scope are defined anew.

CONTEXT SCOPE A property with context scope is inserted into the context and lasts as long as the context or until it is cleared. Once defined, a property in context scope is part of the context. As such, it is available in all logging events, including those sent to remote hosts via serialization.

SYSTEM SCOPE A property with system scope is inserted into the JVM's system properties and lasts as long as the JVM or until it is cleared.

[Source](https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/the-logback-manual/content/en/chapter-3-configuration/configuration-file-syntax/variable-substitution.html#scopes)

Answer (score 0):

the `scope` attribute provided by logback has 3 values(LOCAL, CONTEXT, SYSTEM).It has nothing to do with Spring.the `scope` attribute is used to select different policies when setting properties.

- LOCAL means setting property by InterpretationContext.
- CONTEXT means setting property by Context.
- SYSTEM means setting property by code of System.setProperty(key,value).